# What is this animal in my loft?

Tags: pest-control, pest

I have some animals in my loft, I can hear them scratching around up there.  A month ago it was once a day in the night-time, but now I can hear the noise a few times a day and a few times in the night. I've been up inside the loft and I can't see anything up there at all, no nest or droppings or anything.

Here's a picture of the inside of the loft,  around the area where I hear the scratching most often. I've lifted up the insulation and I can't see anything under it either. There's loads of spaces where the animals might be getting in from one of the neighbouring houses. Why do animals even want to be in my loft if they're not making some kind of a nest up there?

[image]

I made [a recording](https://www.dropbox.com/s/6ghrjk987nb2fcf/LoftAnimalNoise.m4a?dl=0) of the scratching noise that I'm hearing.  Does anybody know what animal this noise is likely to be?  I guess maybe pigeons or rats? I live in a terraced house in the north of England.

My landlord's response is that he can't see anything, therefore there's probably no animals. Is there anything I can say to him, apart from showing him the recording, to encourage him to do something about it? Is there any other way for me to find any additional evidence about the animals? Maybe there's something I can see if I look more carefully in the loft?

Comment: set up a wildlife cam

Comment: Please [edit] your post then drag & drop your picture into the post itself. Not everyone can access Dropbox. Plus, it's nice to not make people click away just to look at a picture that SE will host for you.

Comment: ok I think I've done what you asked

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I dont think birds would be so sneaky.  It is going to be a mammal.

You can catch it.

[image: havahart trap]

[source](https://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/B078FYJZM4/ref=sspa_dk_detail_4?psc=1&pd_rd_i=B078FYJZM4&pd_rd_w=qPgjo&pf_rd_p=1055d8b2-c10c-4d7d-b50d-96300553e15d&pd_rd_wg=9aM89&pf_rd_r=JPMT60ECZN220ZXDS6X0&pd_rd_r=ef9209f8-0d88-4e6f-847b-65a4a037c7b2&spLa=ZW5jcnlwdGVkUXVhbGlmaWVyPUEzNDRYMFEzU0Y0TEo3JmVuY3J5cHRlZElkPUEwODM3MTI0MzJTOEpJUFhGMzFVMSZlbmNyeXB0ZWRBZElkPUEwMzA2MDg3MkhJR1NKVkVIVktCQSZ3aWRnZXROYW1lPXNwX2RldGFpbCZhY3Rpb249Y2xpY2tSZWRpcmVjdCZkb05vdExvZ0NsaWNrPXRydWU=)

I like live catching over poison because poisoned animals die and rot and stink.
Once you catch one you can display it to your landlord.  Then he can pay for a pest control person to come catch the rest and most importantly, seal up the way they are coming in.  Your landlord should be enthusiastic about protecting his property.

In case it is not a rat but a squirrel, or a hedgehog or a bogle or whatever you have in the UK, you will be able to get a good look at it and plan accordingly.

Comment: with some success I've used ultrasonic pest deterrents to keep the critters away, Get good ones with good ratings. Also, get some old fashioned moth balls, mice, rats and other vermin actually have quite sensitive senses of smell and can't stand the smell of moth balls. Place them where you think the critters are and you could solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the different ideas. How would the ultrasonic thing work? Would I be able to plug it in in my bedroom below the loft? There's no plug sockets in the loft itself. I had a look and traps are cheaper than I expected so I might try that

Comment: Now that you mention it, I have seen more bogles around than I usually do at this time of year...

Answer (score 0):

Squirrels are classic. They move in as winter comes, usually.

If you have a landlord, you've informed your landlord, and your landlord isn't interested, you've done what you can do as a person with a landlord.

Make a truce with the (probable squirrels) and move on with your life.

If you owned the house, traps and blocking up access points would be a typical next step. Not your problem...

Comment: Oh the noise is driving me crazy it's keeping me awake at night, otherwise I'd be happy to welcome my new neighbours

Comment: Yeah, I'd never sleep a wink with that going on. In fact, last spring I was in the same boat. Never found the bugger.